# Best way to restrict node names for a SpriteKit transition

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Simple SpriteKit scene. Some nodes have names. I would like to perform a transition only when certain nodes are tapped/clicked. So after some hacking around I settled on creating a Set of String and the code below...

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if let nodeName: String? = node.name {
        if nodeName != nil && questionKeys.contains(nodeName!) {
            transitionToAskScene(nodeName!)
        }

    }
 }
```

I was hoping to not have a nested if statement and simple use one check. Though the first check still runs even when nodeName is nil (I'm guessing because it is an Objective-C nil not a Swift optional?) This works, but does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are up to date (xcode 7)  you could probably write your code like this.  It seems like your question is more about how to avoid using the nested ifs

```
if let nodeName = node.name where questionKeys.contains(nodeName) {
    print("cool")
}
```

Comment: Duh. I'm still trying to make this syntax stick. Thanks.